# JavaScript variable reassigning values

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have made a website which allows you to watch multiple `iframes`, and by using a JavaScript prompt function you can choose the `iframe` source yourself, however I cannot manage to make it possible to change  the source twice. Only once. How can I continue?

```
<script>
function functie1(x) {
var z = "jasonr";
var x = prompt("Which chat do you want to see?", "Shroud");
if (x == "") {
   window.alert("You canceled.");
   location.reload();
} else {
   window.alert("You chose " + x );                                                               
   document.getElementById( z ).src = "https://www.twitch.tv/" + x + "/chat?popout=";
   document.getElementById( z ).id = x;  
}}
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = functie1;
function functie2(y) {
var k = "lirik";
var y = prompt("Which chat do you want to see?", "lirik");
if (y == "") {
   window.alert("You canceled.");
   location.reload();
} else {
   window.alert("You chose " + y)
   document.getElementById( k ).src = "https://www.twitch.tv/" + y + "/chat?popout=";
   document.getElementById( k ).id = y;
}}
document.getElementById("clickMe2").onclick = functie2;
var y = k;
var x = z;
</script>
```

Basically I want the old "default" `z` to become a new `z` with the value that is also in `x`. What is wrong with the variable scopes? I have looked all over and haven't gotten much wiser.

Comment: do you want z? to change each time functie1(x) is called? Currently z is always set to "jasonr" when functie1 is called. try moving var z outside of the function. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I've tried this already, it doesn't end up working. Thank you for the reply nevertheless.

Comment: ah perhaps it is an issue around binding the click event, have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/bxjqu0df/ and see what you think

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bxjqu0df/3/ (edit updated fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the issue is this line:

```
document.getElementById( z ).id = x;
```

That changes the ID of the frame from (say) `jasonr` to whatever the Twitch chat's name is, so next time you do

```
document.getElementById( z )
```

it can't find it — `z` is still `jasonr` but there's no longer an element called that on your page. Just delete the whole line and it should work.